# How does the $localStorage in angularjs works?

Tags: angularjs

Can anybody help me out from how to use **$localStorage** in *angularjs*, I can't find a complete guide for it.

```
I need explanation and syntax for usage such as,
localStorage.getItem();
localStorage.removeItem();
localStorage.clear();
localStorage.setItem();
```

Providing entire doc would help me well.

Comment: Here is article about localStorage (https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Comment: Okay. thanks...i'll look into it.

Comment: I wrote examples from this page to my answer. You can use from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Save to localStorage:**

```
localStorage.setItem("name", value);
```

**Get from localStorage**

```
var x = localStorage.getItem("name");
```

**Remove from localStorage:**

```
localStorage.removeItem("name");
```

**Clear localStorage (remove all):**

```
localStorage.clear();
```

Values in `localStorage` will be exists when you reopen your browser. When you need clear all when you close browser, you must use `sessionStorage`. Usage is same as `localStorage`

Comment: Hey i Got it!!...It works well and I understood the syntax and usage.